# Operation Failed when installing a Nuget Package

Tags: nuget

I have a "new" windows xp sp3 machine with VS2010 SP 1 and Nuget 1.8

Every time a try to add a Nuget Package a receive the following error:

The specified cryptographic algorithm is not supported on this platform.

Does anyone know what does that means?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a known issue with NuGet 1.8 : [NuGet issue#2240](http://nuget.codeplex.com/workitem/2240). The Nuget team will soon (crossing fingers) release a hot fix.

In the meanwhile, I'd suggest installing NuGet 1.7.

EDIT: NuGet released the hotfix (1.8.30524.9000)